# Django Celery AbortableTask usage

Tags: python, django, celery, celery-task

I'm trying to use the [AbortableTask](http://celeryproject.org/docs/reference/celery.contrib.abortable.html) feature of Celery but the documentation example doesn't seem to be working for me.  The example given is:

```
from celery.contrib.abortable import AbortableTask

def MyLongRunningTask(AbortableTask):

    def run(self, **kwargs):
        logger = self.get_logger(**kwargs)
        results = []
        for x in xrange(100):
            # Check after every 5 loops..
            if x % 5 == 0:  # alternatively, check when some timer is due
                if self.is_aborted(**kwargs):
                    # Respect the aborted status and terminate
                    # gracefully
                    logger.warning("Task aborted.")
                    return None
            y = do_something_expensive(x)
            results.append(y)
        logger.info("Task finished.")
        return results
```

and

```
from myproject.tasks import MyLongRunningTask

def myview(request):

    async_result = MyLongRunningTask.delay()
    # async_result is of type AbortableAsyncResult

    # After 10 seconds, abort the task
    time.sleep(10)
    async_result.abort()

    ...
```

However, I am getting the error:

```
TypeError: MyLongRunningTask() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a guess but I think it should be

```
class MyLongRunningTask(AbortableTask)
```

and not

```
def MyLongRunningTask(AbortableTask)
```

Comment: I gave this a shot (makes sense) but the error persisted.  I must not be calling the task right.

Comment: I gave this another try, since it seemed like it would be right, and it works now.  I'm assuming I just hadn't updated the file with the task.